# TFS Build 2010 with Windows Workflow Copy files

Tags: tfs, build, workflow-activity

I am new to Windows Workflow but very familiar with MSbuild and TFS.  For some reason I can't wrap my head around Windows Workflow, so I hope someone could help me.  I'm also really familiar with XAML from a WPF standpoint but I haven't figured out Windows Workflow yet.

For one of my source control projects, all I want the build to do is copy all the files in source control under a certain directory, to a local directoy on the build server.  As well as increment build number, but that activity is included with the default template so I think I can handle that.  I don't need to compile or build any projects.  I don't need to run unit tests or anything like that.  These are just files kept in source control that need to be copied from one place to another.

I've seen some blogs on copy files and that activity seems pretty easy to write, but I'm not sure what part of the default template I need to remove, I'm not sure where I should be adding this copy file activity, I'm just really confused when it comes to Windows Workflow for building projects in TFS.  Any helP?

Thanks!

Comment: Use TeamCity and be happy. No editing xml files for simple tasks.

Comment: Also, Incremental build numbers applied to your DLLs is _NOT_ part of the default TFS process template as far as I can tell. But if you are not building anything, I guess that isn't what you were asking.

Comment: I haven't heard of TeamCity but it does seem nice.  We already TFS for other bigger projects, this is just a small side project that we also use for TFS, so ideally I'd like to build it in there

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the default template, consider using the Upgrade template. As [Executing legacy MSBuild scripts in TFS 2010 Build](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/05/05/executing-legacy-msbuild-scripts-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx) describes it:

> The upgrade template will wrap a very simple workflow around a simple
> **msbuild** workflow activity which only does one thing: run
> TFSBuild.proj. When it runs TFSBuild.proj it will pass in all the
> typical parameters that msbuild will need to use the previous approach
> for building TFSBuild.proj. The advantage to this approach is that
> it's fairly simple and straightforward and you can still add as many
> other activities as you see fit.

So you can basically just continue using your MSBUILD skills to get the job done!

Comment: right, I figured I could always go that route, but why did microsoft decide to go the windows workflow route then?  I was very comfortable with MSBuild before, I was just trying to do a 'simple' thing using Windows Workflow, but it's hard to find good examples and quite frankly understand what is going on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong! There is a build activity available that will copy files from one folder to the other. But it will require you to change your workflow template and find a good place to put your activity with respect to the other activities and configure its variables. I was just under the impression that with your deep knowledge of MSBuild it would be easiest and fastest to continue doing that for this excercise. If you want to go workflow, look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2010/01/21/deep-dive-on-windows-workflow-4-0-activities.aspx.